# Add item to every object in array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making a kind of Trivial Pursuit game. I have the thousands of questions and answers; see example below:

```
var trivialPursuitCards = [
   {
    question: "What nationality was Chopin?",
    answer: ["American", "Polish", "German", "Czech"],
    difficulty: 2
   }, 
   {
    question: "Who cut Van Gogh's ear?",
    answer: ["His sister", "His brother", "Himself", "He was born that way"],
    difficulty: 2
   }
];
```

Now I just need to add one more property to each card namely: `rightAnswer: undefined`.

What is the best way to get this done for all the cards?

Comment: Non-existing properties are undefined by default so it seems unlikely that you'd need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `map` then add your property:-

```js
var trivialPursuitCards = [{
  question: "What nationality was Chopin?",
  answer: ["American", "Polish", "German", "Czech"],
  difficulty: 2
}, {
  question: "Who cut Van Gogh's ear?",
  answer: ["His sister", "His brother", "Himself", "He was born that way"],
  difficulty: 2
}];

var update = trivialPursuitCards.map(function(e, i) {
  e.rightAnswer = undefined;
  return e;
});

console.log(update);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i=0; i<trivialPursuitCards.length; i++) {
    trivialPursuitCards[i].rightAnswer = undefined;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o0pa4z0w/

Answer (score 0):

`trivialPursuitCards.map(function (card) { card.rightAnswer = null; });`

Because it's better to add a `null` than `undefined` since the `rightAnswer` should exist, but currently isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Juhana:

> Non-existing properties are undefined by default so it seems unlikely that you'd need to set it explicitly.

However, if you really want to do this, you can use `Array.prototype.map()`:

```
trivialPursuitCards = trivialPursuitCards.map(element=>
  element.rightAnswer = undefined
)
```